# Are low SAR phones better for health than high SAR phones?

Tags: physics, radiation, mobile-phones

Each device will have a different SAR value and follow this side
https://www.rfsafe.com/samsung-cell-phones-rated-lowest-radiation-cell-phones/
they have say low SAR phone better than high SAR phone

> FACT: Users of the twenty highest SAR cell phones sold in the U.S. can
>   absorb up to four times as much radiation in their heads as users of
>   the twenty lowest SAR cell phones.

But in some side http://www.earthcalm.com/dont-get-fooled-sar-ratings they say
New Information about SAR Ratings

> Unfortunately, after the FCC’s initial report, new evidence came out
>   about SAR in 2010, that a low-SAR phone doesn’t give you a safety
>   advantage after all. In fact, it was determined that it can actually
>   be worse than a high-SAR phone.
>
> This is because some low-SAR phones emit higher total SAR in brain
>   tissue than higher-SAR phones—it’s just spread out a lot more
>   throughout your brain tissue.
>
> And the reason these low-SAR phones emit higher total SAR is that
>   they’re less efficient at getting their signal to the base station and
>   so need to work at a much higher rate to compensate. The FCC finally
>   admitted their mistake—but for some reason, the information didn’t get
>   out well to the general public.

So if both phone is in the same environment, low SAR phone or high SAR phone will better for health? Or I can not compare it base on SAR value

Comment: Really, when all this bullshit about cellphones and radiation will end? It's getting really old now. (Not a critic to the OP, mostly to the media in general)

Comment: Also, it's worth to note that for one to be "better" than the other, they must do some sort of damage to one's health - which, as far as we know, they don't at all. This question, and the claim behind it, is meaningless.

Comment: It would surely help if you explained the SAR abbreviation in your post...

Comment: This question is irrelevant until a causal relation between health and normal cell phone use has been proven. *Then* it would be a sensible question. Voting to close as one of the many 'mobile phone health' questions.

Comment: Once again a scare story about phones that bandies the word "radiation" around willy nilly.  It's a word that's a real gift to scaremongers because a) it sounds really scary but b) it's actually so vague as to be meaningless.  Radiation could mean heat, light, radio waves, even noise if you want to use the broadest possible definition of "radiation" as "anything that radiates from a source".

Comment: @JanDoggen I "think" it means Specific Absorption Rate.  Though again this feels fairly meaningless without a more specific definition of radiation.